# Github Actions Azure CI

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, azure-deployment

I am trying to use github actions to create CI / CD to my azure app service. I followed the steps to the T and I'm getting the following error:

`MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.`

This is what my folder structure looks like :

```
Dev-Blog
   - Dev-Blog
      - *entire solution*
   - .github
      - workflows
         - DeployToAzure.yml
   - .vs
   - .gitignore
   - README.md
```

As you can see, my workflow is inside the `.github` file at the root level. Well, when I navigate there via command line and try to run `dotnet build`, I get essentially get the same error. I don't understand how I am supposed to get my workflow to build properly.

Here is my yml file:

```yaml
name: Deploy to Azure

on: [push]

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: *myAppName* 
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'     
  DOTNET_VERSION: '3.1.x'           

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout the repo
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      
      # Setup .NET Core SDK
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} 
      
      # Run dotnet build and publish
      - name: dotnet build and publish
        run: |
          dotnet restore
          dotnet build --configuration Release
          dotnet publish -c Release -o '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/Dev-Blog' 
          
      # Deploy to Azure Web apps
      - name: 'Run Azure webapp deploy action using publish profile credentials'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with: 
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }} 
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE  }} 
          package: '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/Dev-Blog'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that your project can be compiled and run normally locally, it is recommended to upload github, and then use github for continuous deployment to obtain the automatically generated `.yml` file.

It should be helpful for you to compare the different parts of the file.

**1. Deploy by github.**

[image]

**2. Refresh your repo page and find workflow folder.**

[image]

**3. You can get the automatically generated `.yml` file, and you can also compare with your file.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason! I've been taking a break for a couple days but will attempt this in the next couple days. I will get back to you then! Thank you for the info!

Comment: @AndrewSmith You are welcome! If you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: @AndrewSmith Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: Still on a Thanksgiving break haha flying home today

Comment: So the yml file that I have was automatically generated.

Comment: Is it possible that it generated the workflow folder in the wrong folder?